# search elements of list in another list

Tags: python, list

This may have been already answered but believe me I may be so dumb (I have serious doubts right now) I couldn't even see the solution. To make my issue very simple, let's say I have two lists as follow:
list_1

```
[2, 3, 4]
```

list_2

```
[['2', '54', '65', '22'],['2', '67', '66', '32'], ['10', '11', '43', '90'], ['3', '28', '81', '78'], ['4', '87', '19', '13'], ['4', '30', '51', '92'], ['4', '11', '44', '55'], ['13', '22', '69', '99']]
```

What I'm trying to do is to find if there is any match of any single element of list_1 with any first element of list_2, and if so return the line that will be later written out (but I should be able to do this). 
Practically, in this scenario the result I'm after is:

```
2 54 65 22
2 67 66 32
3 28 81 78
4 87 19 13
4 30 51 92
4 11 44 55
```

I ended up with so many for, if loops and list comprehensions that I lost my count and I acknowledge I'm not much familiar with python rules. Hope I can get any help from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension, just check that first element of each list in b exists in a:

```
a = [2, 3, 4]
b = [['2', '54', '65', '22'],['2', '67', '66', '32'], ['10', '11', '43', '90'], ['3', '28', '81', '78'], ['4', '87', '19', '13'], ['4', '30', '51', '92'], ['4', '11', '44', '55'], ['13', '22', '69', '99']]

c = [x for x in b if int(x[0]) in a]
```

Comment: This seems to work, still testing with my real dataset. Quick question though, wouldn't it be more time efficient to search for each element of a in b rather than the other way around? Or maybe this is the error I was making....

Answer (score 0):

You could just `filter` your `list2`:

```
result = filter(lambda vector: int(vector[0]) in list1, list2)
```

notice that you must convert the strings contained in the lists in `list2` (notice the `'`!) to integers first, that's what `int()` does here.

Comment: You really no need lambda here.